# OSX SDK changing alpha CALayer with CIFIlter

Tags: objective-c, calayer, cifilter

I have the following code for adding the blurred layer to my view:

```
_layerBlurredTable = [CALayer layer];
_layerBlurredTable.frame = self.viewLocalizationInfoHolder.bounds;
CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[blur setDefaults];
_layerBlurredTable.backgroundFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:blur];
_layerBlurredTable.opacity = 0.1;
```

But the layer opacity never change. Is there any way to make this layer more transparent?

Note: I'm using the Mac OSX SDK.

Comment: What do you mean "layer opacity never change"?  That's not what a gaussian blur is supposed to do.

Comment: I want to fade in/out the appearance/exit of the blurred effect. But changing the alphaValue of the CALayer does nothing.

Comment: Well I'm no expert, having never used filters, but I would guess that opacity has no effect when a filter is in use.  I'm guessing this layer is above the layers you want to blur?  How about blurring them directly?

Comment: Blurring the layer directly has negative impact on the performance, because while the blur effect is applied, the NSView is also scrolled. In my experience, changing the alpha value would not be so heavy. Do I know any other technique to achieve something similar?